# Unable to install arcpy module using Pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, arcpy

I realize this has come up before, but all the responses I've found were for different versions of Arc.

I have followed the steps from this [link](https://community.esri.com/thread/219641-can-arcgis-pro-integrate-with-jetbrains-pycharm) and set my project interpreter to python `c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\python.exe`. Based from what i've read, that should be set up with Arcpy pre-installed. However, if I look at the packages in the VENV, arcpy isn't listed. I've tried adding it using pip and the pycharm GUI package manager. There isn't a package just named arcpy, the options are:

- arcpy-metadata
- arcpy-virtualenv
- arcpyext
- arcpylogger

I have successfully installed all of them and they show up in the package list of the project virtual environment. Despite this, I still get "no module named arcpy" as an error when I go to run a script.

Any ideas about where i'm going wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I've spent a while looking over the issue and using Conda as your project Interpreter is the fix to your issue. I've tested it myself as well. Here are some clear instructions on how to correctly install Conda and set up the environment in Pycharm:

**To create a Conda environment﻿:**

Ensure that *Anaconda* or *Miniconda* is downloaded and installed on your computer, and you're aware of a path to its executable file.

*(Refer to the installation instructions for more details.)*

Press *Meta+Comma* to open the project *Settings/Preferences*.

In the *Settings/Preferences* dialog *Meta+Comma*, select *Project  | Project Interpreter*. Click the *The Configure project interpreter* icon and select *Add*.

In the left-hand pane of the *Add Python Interpreter* dialog, select Conda Environment.

**The following actions depend on whether the Conda environment existed before.**

*If New environment is selected:*

Specify the location of the new Conda environment in the text field, or click Conda environment location and find location in your file system. Note that the directory where the new Conda environment should be located, must be empty!

Select the Python version from the list.

Specify the location of the Conda executable file in the text field, or click Conda executable location and find location in the Conda installation directory. You're basically looking for a path that you've used when installing Conda on your machine.

Select the Make available to all projects checkbox, if needed.

*If Existing environment is selected:*

Expand the Interpreter list and select any of the existing interpreters. Alternatively, click Select an interpreter and specify a path to the Conda executable in your file system, for example, C:\Users\jetbrains\Anaconda3\python.exe.

Select the checkbox Make available to all projects, if needed.

Click OK to complete the task.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I do have anaconda installed (just plain anaconda, not via jetbrains), but i'm not sure where to find the conda excutable. I have the miniconda .exe in: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition with Anaconda plugin 2019.1.3\minicondaInstaller\Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe but I dont think thats what you mean. Theres C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe but i'm not sure if thats correct either. Thanks for your time

Comment: The second path you specified should work perfectly for you. Give it a shot and let me know if my answer has benefited you. Good Luck!

Comment: My project interpreter is now set to ...\anaconda3\python.exe in settings but it won't let me create a new script or run a scratch python file as if I had no interpreter defined.

Comment: Can you attach screenshots of the Project Interpreter dialog as well as the path of Anaconda installations if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: C:\Users\{your user}\miniconda3\python.exe - This is the default installation path and that is the file you need to set as the interpreter. I reinstalled miniconda and can confirm this.

Comment: I’ve installed Miniconda properly.  I don’t think it was installed before, I’m not sure what I found, but I don’t think it was right. How does this look? https://imgur.com/a/vqvhqy6

Comment: It looks like you've selected the correct interpreter. Are you still having problems with the module?

Comment: Yes, I made a new project and set the miniconda python version as the default interpreter. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have the arcpy module loaded by default and I can't find arcpy in the package manager for pycharm. Thanks for your time